# Testing Proportional Hazards Assumption in Cure model

Tags: survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, proportional-hazards

I am currently working on estimating a cure survival model where I want to incorporate a Cox proportional hazards (PH) model for the latency part of the model (i.e. the part for the observations that actually experience the event). However, I am unsure about the appropriate approach to test the PH assumption in this specific setup.

In a standard Cox PH model, I am aware of methods such as using statistical tests based on Schoenfeld residuals, which is available in packages like the lifelines library in Python. My question is whether these methods are also applicable to the cure survival model and, if so, what considerations should be taken into account.

When testing the PH assumption for the cure survival model, should I consider restricting my sample to observations that are not cured (i.e., those that actually experience the event of interest)? Or is there an alternative approach that accounts for the unique nature of the cure model?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance you can provide on testing the PH assumption within the context of a cure survival model.